# Positioning two elements in css

Tags: html, css, css-position

```
<div id="homeScreen">
    <div id="homeWrapper">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo-icon"/>
        <img src="ajaxloader.gif" alt="loading.." id="loader"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two images. A logo and a loading image. I need position logo at centre horizontally and vertically and loader at centre at the bottom of page. My CSS is this:

```
#homeScreen
{
    background: #d1d1d1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#homeWrapper
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I'm able to get both images at centre by this code. But I don't need to have loader at same position with logo. I need it to be at the end of page without affecting the position of logo. How to do it?

Comment: A little confused what you mean by "end of page" do you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/vEZzS/

Comment: OP: did you fix your problem? Please [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bit of trouble understanding what exactly you wanted, but this code should align the logo to the center (vertically and horizontally) and the loading icon to the bottom, centrally aligned horizontally.

HTML:

```
<div id="homeScreen">
    <div id="homeWrapper">
        <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo-icon" width="150" height="150"/></div>
        <div id="loading"><img src="ajaxloader.gif" alt="loading.." id="loader" width="30" height="30"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#homeScreen
{
    background: #d1d1d1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#logo
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-75px 0 0 -75px;
}

#loading
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/vEZzS/1/ test your code in fiddle if your not sure.

Comment: @defaultNINJA Apologies, I've fixed it and it now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it at end of page try using the float:right on loader img, so it will be displayed at the end of the row. If you want to show the loader below logo, use a br after logo img.

If you want to center the logo to whole page and display loader at right bottom of page, you can apply the 'vertical-align:middle' to logo and 'vertical-align:bottom;float:right' to loader.

Hope this helps.